# DB2 Create Stored Procedure Error..can anyone provide insight

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

The Error is as follows:

> H1WICTDD.WICQ083A: 44: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE
>   LEGAL ARE: + - ( TRIM XMLSERIALIZE CAST XMLCAST CASE CURRENT_DATE.
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.62.80

The SQL (I get no syntax warnings prior to trying to deploy):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE H1WICTDD.WICQ083a(IN parmCollection VARCHAR(8), IN parmAgencyID CHAR(3), IN parmSQLCODE INT)
    VERSION V1
    ISOLATION LEVEL CS
    RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL
    QUALIFIER H1xxx

P1:BEGIN

DECLARE strAgencyID VARCHAR(3);
DECLARE dtDATE DATE;
DECLARE strServer VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE strUser VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE strLowAgencyID CHAR(3);
DECLARE c_result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR RES_SET;


SET dtDate=(CURRENT DATE - 13 MONTHS);
SET strServer=CURRENT SERVER;
SET strUser=USER;

--SELECT  CURRENT SERVER INTO strServer FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
--SELECT  CURRENT SESSION_USER INTO strUser FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1; 


IF strServer = 'HWDCH1xxx' THEN                                 
    SET strLowAgencyID ='100'; 
ELSE 
    SET strLowAgencyID ='101';
END IF;                           


SELECT GAGENCYID INTO strAgencyID                                      
FROM VINFWICIDUSER                                     
WHERE GUSERID = strUser
WITH UR;                                              

--If strAgencyID of the USER equals the passed in parmAgency ID
--or strAgencyID has astriks (*) then the user has access to statewide
--Reports.  So test taht first.  If passes that test, then see if they 
--want state or agency only

IF strAgencyID=parmAgencyID OR strAgencyID Like '*%' THEN
    IF parmAgencyID=’ALL’ THEN
--STATEWIDE
    SELECT                                                   
         A.GAGENCYID,                                           
         B.GAGENCYNAME,                                         
         A.GPARTICIPMONTH,                                      
         C.GCASELOADCNT,                                        
         A.GPARTICIPATION,                                      
         (C.GCASELOADCNT - A.GPARTICIPATION) AS GCLESSP,          
         COALESCE(SUM(D.GCNTTOTAL),0) AS GUNISSUEDCNT           
       FROM                                                     
         VINFPARTICPSUMM A                                      
         INNER JOIN VINFAGENCY B                                
           ON   B.GAGENCYID = A.GAGENCYID                   
         INNER JOIN VINFCASELOAD C                              
           ON   C.GAGENCYID = A.GAGENCYID                   
         LEFT OUTER JOIN VINFUNISSUEDRX D                       
           ON   D.GAGENCYID = A.GAGENCYID                 
           AND CONCAT(SUBSTR(CHAR(A.GPARTICIPMONTH,ISO ),1,4 ),       
              SUBSTR(CHAR(A.GPARTICIPMONTH,ISO ),6,2 ) )      
             = D.GRXMONTHYEAR                                 
       WHERE                                                   
         A.GPARTICIPMONTH >= dtDATE                     
         AND  A.GAGENCYID BETWEEN strLowAgencyID AND '399'  
         AND C.GEFFECTIVEDATE =                                
           (SELECT MAX(E.GEFFECTIVEDATE)                       
           FROM VINFCASELOAD E                                 
           WHERE E.GAGENCYID       = A.GAGENCYID               
             AND E.GEFFECTIVEDATE <= A.GPARTICIPMONTH)         
       GROUP BY   A.GAGENCYID,                                 
         B.GAGENCYNAME,                                        
         A.GPARTICIPMONTH,                                     
         A.GPARTICIPATION,                                     
         C.GCASELOADCNT
         WITH UR;                                                                        

      ELSE
--AGENCY
    SELECT                                                  
         A.GAGENCYID,                                          
         B.GAGENCYNAME,                                        
         A.GPARTICIPMONTH,                                     
         C.GCASELOADCNT,                                       
         A.GPARTICIPATION,                                     
         (C.GCASELOADCNT - A.GPARTICIPATION) AS GCLESSP,         
         COALESCE(SUM(D.GCNTTOTAL),0) AS GUNISSUEDCNT          
       FROM                                                    
         VINFPARTICPSUMM A                                     
         INNER JOIN VINFAGENCY B                               
           ON  B.GAGENCYID = A.GAGENCYID                   
         INNER JOIN VINFCASELOAD C                             
           ON  C.GAGENCYID = A.GAGENCYID                   
         LEFT OUTER JOIN VINFUNISSUEDRX D                      
           ON  D.GAGENCYID = A.GAGENCYID                   
           AND CONCAT(SUBSTR(CHAR(A.GPARTICIPMONTH,ISO),1,4),         
              SUBSTR(CHAR(A.GPARTICIPMONTH,ISO),6,2))          
             = D.GRXMONTHYEAR                                  
       WHERE                                                    
         A.GPARTICIPMONTH >= dtDATE                       
         AND  A.GAGENCYID = parmAgencyID                      
         AND C.GEFFECTIVEDATE =                                 
           (SELECT MAX(E.GEFFECTIVEDATE)                        
           FROM VINFCASELOAD E                                  
           WHERE E.GAGENCYID = A.GAGENCYID                      
             AND E.GEFFECTIVEDATE <= A.GPARTICIPMONTH)          
       GROUP BY   A.GAGENCYID,                                  
         B.GAGENCYNAME,                                         
         A.GPARTICIPMONTH,                                      
         A.GPARTICIPATION,                                      
         C.GCASELOADCNT                                         
 WITH UR;                                   

    END IF;

END IF;
OPEN c_result;
--=============================================================
--Handle Errors and Log them
--==============================================================

        --EXEC Stored Proc WICQ00R (STORPROC_NAME, RETURN_CODE, MISC, strUser, CURRENT DATETIME)

END P1
```

Comment: In a compound statement you can only `SELECT` `INTO` something (or declare a cursor).

Comment: That appears to be the case.  Thanks

Comment: Edited to show error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates line 44, which is

```
IF parmAgencyID=’ALL’ THEN
```

I'm guessing the smartquotes are not intended.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you eveyone.  It appears in DB2 that I can not have conditional logic dictate what SELECT statement to use.  I must DECLARE a CURSOR before each SELECT statement and then put the conditional logic at the bottom and OPEN the appropriate CuRSOR.  I moved the following code to the bottom of the PROCEDURE:

```
SET DTDATE=(CURRENT DATE - 13 MONTHS);
SET STRSERVER=CURRENT SERVER;
SET STRUSER=USER;

SELECT GAGENCYID INTO STRAGENCYID FROM VINFWICIDUSER                                     
WHERE GUSERID = STRUSER;

IF STRSERVER = 'HWDCH1TD' THEN                                 
    SET STRLOWAGENCYID ='100'; 
ELSE 
    SET STRLOWAGENCYID ='101';
END IF;  

IF STRAGENCYID = PARMAGENCYID OR STRAGENCYID LIKE '*%' THEN 
    IF PARMAGENCYID = 'ALL' THEN
        OPEN C_STATE;  --The DECLARED CURSOR in first SELECT
    ELSE
        OPEN C_AGENCY; --The DECLARED CURSOR in the second SELECT
    END IF;
END IF;
--=============================================================
--Handle Errors and Log them
--==============================================================
        --EXEC Stored Proc WICQ00R (STORPROC_NAME, RETURN_CODE, MISC, strUser, CURRENT DATETIME) 
END P1
```

We have a reporting system that has trouble with CURSORS so not sure what where I will head...

Thanks for the replies.